# Access allow addings but no edits in certain columns in a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, identity-column, subform

I got question if it is possible to allow addings but no edits in certain columns in a subform? I can do this for the whole form, but i can't do this for single columns.

For example:

[image]

I want to be able to allow edits in [Type], and in [Omschrijving] I only want to allow adds and no edits.

I can lock certain columns. For example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Omschrijving.Locked = True
End Sub
```

But then I'm not able to make any adds. Is there another way to make this possible?

Comment: You could hook on certain events to prevent the user from deleting anything: This among others: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.beforedelconfirm(even)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only lock if not a new record. Use form Current event instead of Load.

```
If Not Me.NewRecord Then
   Me.Omschrijving.Locked = True
End If
```

Might use Enabled property instead so control shows as unavailable for edit, in which case could use Conditional Formatting for textboxes and comboboxes instead of VBA. Rule something like:
`Expression is: Not Forms!formname.NewRecord`
Then click the Enable/Disable button so if this condition is met, control is disabled.